# What happens to the values of duplicate keys in a tree map

Tags: java, treemap

I have a text file which is read into a Tree Map. The Text File contains a list of students and their marks.

```
Harry 10
Sam    8
John   7
Harry  8
Sam    9
```

I have tried writing this code, which reads a file, stores it in the Tree Map and displays it on the console.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("marks.txt"));
    TreeMap<String, Integer> students = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        students.put(columns[0], Integer.parseInt(columns[1]));
    }
    System.out.println("Alpha Order");
    // Iterate over TreeMap
    for (String key : students.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " :: " + students.get(key));
    }
```

The output I get on the console after executing the code is

```
Alpha Order
Harry :: 10
John :: 7
Sam :: 9
```

I need the other values for further computations. is it possible to have an output like

```
Harry :: 10 8
John  ::  7
Sam   ::  9 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the values will be replaced since a Map only allows one key -> value mapping.

The easiest way of mapping multiple values to a key is to use a multi(value)map. I prefer [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("marks.txt"));
TreeMultimap<String, Integer> students = TreeMultimap.create();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    students.put(columns[0], Integer.parseInt(columns[1]));
}
System.out.println("Alpha Order");
// Iterate over TreeMap
for (String key : students.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + " :: " + String.join(", ", students.get(key)));
}
```

But if you can't add dependencies you can use a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("marks.txt"));
TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>> students = new TreeMap<>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    String student = columns[0];
    TreeSet<Integer> set;
    if(students.containsKey(student)) {
        // A set already exists in the map for this student,
        // append to it
        set = students.get(student);
    } else {
        // No set exists in the map for this student,
        // create a new one and put it in the map
        set = new TreeSet<>();
        students.put(student, set);
    }
    set.add(Integer.parseInt(columns[1]));
}
System.out.println("Alpha Order");
// Iterate over TreeMap
for (String key : students.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + " :: " + String.join(", ", students.get(key)));
}
```

Note that these two are using sets so won't allow duplicate key -> value mappings. I.e. you can't get this output:

```
Harry :: 10 8 8
John  ::  7 7
Sam   ::  9 9 8
```

That's easy to achieve with the latter solution though by just replacing the `TreeSet` with an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to the values of duplicate keys in a tree map

The old values of duplicate keys are replaced.  If a `Map` finds that the key already exists, then it replaces the value.  E.g.

```
"Harry" => 10
```

becomes

```
"Harry" => 8
```

> is it possible to have an output like

Yes, but you need to maintain a `List<Integer>` as your value.

Instead of just blindly `put`ting the key/value pair, test if the key already exists with `containsKey`.  If the key already exists, `get` the list and `add` the value to it.  If the key doesn't exist yet, then create a new `List`, add the value to it, and `put` the key/value into the `Map`.

E.g.

```
"Harry" => [10]
```

to

```
"Harry" => [10, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

A map does exactly that; it maps from a key, to a value.

So when you read the second input for Harry, it replaces the previous value.

If you need to map to multiple values, you can have the map be a map from name, to a collection of Integer.

For example:

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    //...
    if(map.containsKey(name) == false)
        map.put(name,  new LinkedList<Integer>());
    map.get(name).add(score);
```